# Consider the following two sentences. Are these sentences grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Consider the following two sentences. Are these sentences grammatically correct?

> A) If majority of the individuals in a State prosper the State itself
>   would prosper.
>
> B) To die with honor is better than live with dishonor.

This is my attempt:

> If majority of the individuals in a State prosper the State itself
>   will prosper.
>
> To die with honor is better than to live with dishonor.

Am I right?

Comment: I suggest that "If majority of the individuals" should be "If the majority of individuals."

Answer (score 1):

A:

> If the majority of individuals in a state prosper then the state itself will also prosper.

A(alternative):

> If the majority of individuals in a state prosper, the state itself will also prosper.

B:

> To die with honour is better than to live with dishonour.

B(alternative):

> To die with honour is better than living with dishonour.

Hope this helps